# CSS grid making iframe unresponsive

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-grid, responsive

I am attempting to organize an embedded iframe video on my HTML page (Chrome browser) by using CSS gridlines. However, it seems that the grid area is "overlaying" the iframe, making it so that I can't click on anything in the iframe. If I move the iframe out of the gridline area, then it becomes responsive again.

After a lot of searching, I still can't find a solution to this question, so posting one here. How can I make my iframe video responsive while still keeping my content organized?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-left: -20%;
  /* Defines grid-template-columns and grid-template-areas values */
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 40% 30%;
  grid-template-areas: 'pic header header' 'pic video video' '. video video';
}
```

```html
<!--Gridline wrapper/ container-->
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="text header">Some text</div>
  <img class="pic" src="./image.png">
  <!--problematic iframe-->
  <iframe class="video" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LHgAz4CADmw" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>
```

I've tried adjusting the z-index in the hopes that moving the iframe forward would help, but to no avail. I've also tried adding padding to the wrapper and using a CSS grid query to adjust the layout. Neither of those worked either.

Comment: The problem is at your `zindex: -1` in your grid container. All the childs are in this new stacking context now. Any reasons why it needs to be -1?

Comment: That worked to fix it!! Thank you so very much! The z-index was a legacy from a previous debugging session. Seriously, thank you so much!